# How to sort the self-reference structure?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

In my Spring Boot application, there is the model "Item" which has sefl-reference. I would like to realize sorting by field sortOrder, but I can't understand how to implement it for CRUD operations.
For instance, how to get the value for sortOrder before saving my entity to the repository and how to recalculate sortOrder after updating the entity. Any help will be highly appreciated! Thanks!

```
@Data
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "item")
public class Item {

    @Id
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING)
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "itemSeq", sequenceName = "item_id_seq", allocationSize = 50)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY, generator = "itemSeq")
    private Long id;

    @NotBlank
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;

    @Column(name = "sort_order")
    private String sortOrder;

    @Column(name = "is_active")
    private Boolean isActive;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id")
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING)
    @JsonIgnoreProperties({"name", "description", "sortOrder", "isActive", "parent", "children"})
    private Item parent;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @Where(clause = "is_active = true")
    @Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
    @OrderBy("sort_order ASC")
    private List<Item> children = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the new entity you want to save has a sort_order of x,

First you will have to increment all the other columns which has sort_order >= x. The easiest way you can do it is by using a native query.

```
@Modifying
@Query("update item set sort_order = sort_order + 1 where sort_order >= ?1", nativeQuery = true)
int incrementSortOrders(int currentSortOrder);
```

After this, its just a matter of saving your new entity using

```
repository.save(item)
```

---

Update:

If the sort_order is something of the format 1-3-0, 1-3-1, 1-3-2, 1-3-3 to indicate a recursive order, Then this is one possible solution -

Suppose we get the new entity with sort key 1-3-1,

1. we can still identify the items to be incremented with the > operator as they will be lexicographically larger.
2. We can calculate the prefix of the current node sequnce as `1-3-` by writing the logic in code

Then we can run the following query to increment every other row.

```
@Modifying
@Query("update item set sort_order = CONCAT(:prefix ,CONVERT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(sort_order, :prefix, -1), UNSIGNED INTEGER) + 1) where sort_order > :currentNodeOrder", nativeQuery = true)
int incrementSortOrders(String prefix, String currentNodeOrder); //prefix is `1-3-` which was pre calculated and current node order is `1-3-1`
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Maybe you know some of the best practices to implement a sortOrder value for the sefl-reference case? For example, I know that UI libraries use a specific value like 0-1-0 -> 0-1-1 for describing a tree-like relationship. I think in my case I should implement something close. I can't imagine how to do it and how to update after change some element's orders.

Comment: I am still not that clear on your problem. These are my doubts. Would you be having an overall sort order across the table for all elements? When you get an entity to update, what information do you get in the request based on which you sort?

Comment: In perspective, my service will get the entity with some sortOrder value like 0-2 from the client-side. Nonetheless, in the case when I will have а structure with a great number of the element on the second level, I should update all my elements from the previous 0-2 until 0-99. I would like to use the most optimized way for it.